# porting application from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, glib

I have to port a console application from Linux to Windows.
My collegue suggest to use the command:
`gcc foggycsv.c -o foggycsv.exe`
where foggycsv.c is the file where the code is written.
And the previous creator use these library:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <libmachinery/machinery.h>
#include <libmachinery/ethercat-slaves.h>
#include <modbus.h>
```

And when I execute the first command is says

> glib.h: No such file or directory

And I guess i'm gonna have trouble with also the other libraries; how can I retrieve them for windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of a Win libraries of Glib

Check Cygwin or MYSYS
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
or
https://www.msys2.org/

You need to download the glib libraries and link your application.

Please do some homework :)

Comment: `Please do some homework :)` I didnt ask for judgement. Anyways, Thanks for the suggestion, I'm gonna try the first link. I tried with msys2 but had problems adn could resolve anything